# Allow Chrome autocompletion but no prompt for certain field

Tags: html, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I have a form with multiple inputs, one of which is countries. I created my own dropdown box for the list of countries. I am using form_for, and I would like the browser's autocomplete to fill in this field if they select an autocomplete option on a different field in the form, but I do not want it to prompt the user only on this particular input field (as it gets in the way of my dropdown).

```
            <%= form.text_field :country,
                id: :sender_address_country,
                class: "form-control country-search",
                autocomplete: "off" %>
```

I have tried the :autocomplete and :autofill options I've seen in responses to similar questions in various combinations. :autocomplete works to stop the autocomplete prompt but does not allow the user to autofill if they select an autocomplete option from the first field in the form. Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Something of a work around, but I decided to add a JavaScript effect to the field adding the autocomplete attribute while the field is focused, and it is removed when focus is removed.

```
$('.country-search').focusout(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('autocomplete');
});

$('.country-search').focusin(function () {
    $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
})
```